# how to write mongodb $near query in mongoid dsl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, mongoid, geospatial

I've this this mongodb query and i want to write it in mongoid dsl, if possible

```
    db.pokemons.find(
       {
         target_region :
           { $near :
              {
                $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [-80.190262, 25.774252] },
                $minDistance: 1110,
                $maxDistance: 5000
              }
           }
       }
    )
```

Comment: You might wanna explore http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/querying.html#geo_near

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you are getting the coordinates through params[:coordinates]

```
clocation = params[:coordinates].split(",").map(&:to_f)
max_distance = params[:max_distance].to_i 
min_distance = params[:min_distance].to_i
```

If you want to measure through **`point`** then use this

```
Pokemon.where(:target_region => {"$near" => clocation , '$maxDistance' => max_distance, '$minDistance' => min_distance})
```

If you want to measure through **`miles`** then use this

```
Pokemon.where(:target_region => {"$near" => clocation , '$maxDistance' => max_distance.fdiv(69), '$minDistance' => min_distance.fdiv(69)})
```

If you want to measure through **`kilometers`** then use this

```
Pokemon.where(:target_region => {"$near" => clocation , '$maxDistance' => max_distance.fdiv(111.12), '$minDistance' => min_distance.fdiv(111.12)})
```

Comment: Not working

  `@skip=0 @limit=0 @selector={"target_region"=>{"$near"=>[-80.190262, 25.774252], "$maxDistance"=>5000000, :isNearSphere=>true}} @fields=nil> failed with error 17007: "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=mobadz_development.campaigns limit=0 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR field=target_region maxdist=5e+006 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query" See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md for details about this error.`

Comment: Not working for me. It gives me the above error
  
 `Pokemon.where(:target_region => {"$near" => clocation , '$maxDistance' => 5000000})`

 
I did  create index on :target_region field
  `db.campaigns.ensureIndex({target_region : "2dsphere"})`

Comment: Did you used `index({target_region: "2d"})` in `Pokemon` model?

Comment: Also your field should be declared as such.  `field :target_region, type: Array, :default => [] # [lat,lng]`

Comment: yep, i tried "2d" index as well. My field is geoJSON and is declared as `field :target_region, type: hash # {type:"Polygon", coordinates: [[ [log,lat], [long,lat] ] ] `

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
Pokemon.geo_near([-80.190262, 25.774252]).min_distance(1110).max_distance(5000)
```

Also check The mongoid docs for reference
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#geo_near